# Vertically expanding search box html css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make an expandible search box for a navbar. When the user clicks on the searchbox this should expand showing also another input box with a different name input.
I would like to have such two searchbox one under the other.

This is my current implementation:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg py-2 fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
              <h7 id="nick"><strong class="d-none d-lg-inline">myLogo</strong></h7></a>
              <form class="my-auto w-75" method="get" action="">
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control border border-right-0 ui-autocomplete-input" id="search"
                          name="search" placeholder="Cerca..." autocomplete="off">
                      <span class="input-group-append">
                          <button class="btn btn-outline-light border border-left-0 p-3" style="border-bottom-left-radius: 0%; border-top-left-radius: 0%; background-color: #f18918;" type="submit">
                              Cerca
                          </button>
                      </span>
                  </div>
              </form>
              <a class="navbar-icon" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#sidebar" role="button" aria-controls="sidebar"><i class="bi bi-person-circle"></i></a>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

Any idea?

Comment: This is not pure HTML and CSS, Please create a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using the tools you specified.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have fixed the code and placed it into a runnable snippet

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. That's critical information. Also, `h7` is not a thing. Use a good editor or an HTML validator to make problems more apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created another search field copying the first one and added a click event on the first search field with JavaScript to display the 2nd input field. The codes are very basic and self explanatory. I think you can do the other adjustment by yourself if necessary. If you still have any question feel free to ask.

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#search').style.height = "100%";
  document.querySelector('#search2').style.display = "none";
})

document.querySelector('#search').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  this.style.height = "50%"; // Decreasing the height of the input for showing 2 one below another
  document.querySelector('#search2').style.display = "block"; // Showing the 2nd input field on click
})

document.querySelector('#search2').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
})

document.querySelector('.input-group-append').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg py-2 fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
      <h7 id="nick"><strong class="d-none d-lg-inline">myLogo</strong></h7>
    </a>

    <form class="my-auto w-75" method="get" action="">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div style="flex: 1;">
          <input type="text" class="form-control border border-right-0 ui-autocomplete-input" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Cerca..." autocomplete="off" style="height: 100%;">

          <input type="text" class="form-control border border-right-0 ui-autocomplete-input" id="search2" name="search2" placeholder="Cerca2..." autocomplete="off" style="height: 50%; display: none;">
        </div>

        <span class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-light border border-left-0 p-3" style="border-bottom-left-radius: 0%; border-top-left-radius: 0%; background-color: #f18918; height: 100%;" type="submit">
                Cerca
            </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </form>

    <a class="navbar-icon" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#sidebar" role="button" aria-controls="sidebar"><i class="bi bi-person-circle"></i></a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have a couple of questions. Does there exist also a way so that if the user clicks outside of the two input field (and not on the submit button) the second input collapses?

Comment: Sure, it is possible. You have to combine conditional logic with those click events to do that.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: OK, I added the logic here and now it will work exactly how you wanted. If it helps then you can give upvote to the answer and mark is as "accepted answer" if you want.